# Citation for Continuous Space Hill Climbing Algorithm pseudocode on Wikipedia?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, genetic-algorithms, search-theory

Can anyone provide a reference for the Continuous Space Hill Climbing Algorithm pseudocode in the Wikipedia article on Hill Climbing? The Russell and Norvig text is cited, but they only provide the discrete case. I'm wondering where this particular version of the continuous case is first described.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing

Comment: I tracked down the contributor who posted that pseudocode; it looks like he's still around, so I left him a message with a link to this question. So maybe he'll show up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are pretty close matches:

Yuret, D. From Genetic Algorithms to Efficient Organization. Cambridge (MA): Massachusetts Institute of Technology; 1994. AI Technical Report No. 1569. (Available [here](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AITR-1569.pdf))

Rosete, A., Ochoa, A., Sebag, M. “Automatic Graph Drawing and Stochastic Hill Climbing”, Proceedings of Genetic and Evolutionary Computation Conference, GECCO-99, Orlando, Banzhaf, W. Daida, J. Eiben, A. E. Garzon, M. H. Honavar, V. Jakiela, M. Smith, R. E. (Eds.), Morgan-Kaufmann, Vol. 2, 1699-1706, Julio 1999. (Available [here](ftp://ftp.cs.bham.ac.uk/.snapshot/nightly.0/pub/authors/W.B.Langdon/biblio/gecco1999/RW-726f.pdf))

Comment: Welcome to the site, @JohnForbes. One of our goals for CV is to develop a permanent repository of actionable information about stats in the form of answers to questions. As such, one thing we worry about is link rot. Would you mind editing your answer to include a standard citation, in case those links go dead? Since you're new here, you may want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about) & our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which contain info like this.